# UITableViewCell appearance in IB different than during run time

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, runtime

iPhone dev question!

So i have a custom UITableViewCell class, and i have configured it in Interface Builder with a height of 79. My problem is that once i run the app, the cells have a height of only 20. I can't figure out why the two are different.

If anyone has encountered this before, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you put UITableViewCell into UITableView, the height of cell is fetched from this delegate function - - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {return 79;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have forgot to implement heightForRowAtIndexPath method of table view in your Viewcontroller's .m file . in that method just add "return 79" . This will solve your problem

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. solved it already, but thanks for the reply!